# How do i connect/open/link file with my application?

Tags: c++, qt, plugins

When I saved file using my application. Then, I open it directly on folder saved. It cannot use my application to open this file i save.

Is there some code to open a file directly using my application?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure there is, somewhere, "some code to open a file directly using my application". HTH. HAND.

Comment: oh, like when i double click the file , application automatically open, i mean

Comment: There is a real answer here, in fact it strongly depends on the OS you're running. And I know that it's not straightforward. For example on macs there's a `xml` `plist` file inside the `.app` that handles the extensions handled by the app (http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/mac-differences.html#info-plist-and-application-icon). @Noooobz2016, please expand your question

Comment: @bibi Thank you, i got it. How about using linux?

Comment: look at this: http://askubuntu.com/a/251738

Comment: What operating systems / desktops are you targeting ?

Comment: Linux Operating System like Ubuntu

Comment: Ok, in that case, this question is a duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41195/how-to-change-the-default-program-for-a-specific-file-extension-system-wise-in-k